# pig load xml and property

Tags: java, xml, apache-pig

xml data like below:

```
<test>
    <Step TestResultInfo=" " TestElapsedTimeSec="0" TestResult="Pass" StepNumber="1" GUIResponseTime="0" TestDateTimeStarted="11/20/2012 11:01:14 PM" StepDescription="Ampere CMQMR -- Map CMQMR Driver" StepName="ProcMapCMQMRDriver_Foxconn"/>
    <Step TestResultInfo=" " TestElapsedTimeSec="0" TestResult="Pass" StepNumber="2" GUIResponseTime="0" TestDateTimeStarted="11/20/2012 11:01:14 PM" StepDescription="Factory CIM check" StepName="ProcCheckFactoryCIMSetup_Foxconn"/>
    -<Step TestResultInfo=" " TestElapsedTimeSec="1" TestResult="Pass" StepNumber="3" GUIResponseTime="0.14" TestDateTimeStarted="11/20/2012 11:01:14 PM" StepDescription="Establish Connection" StepName="ProcSetVerifyCommunication">
        +<DataLog TestResult="PASS" TableName="ccProcSetVerifyCommunicationRes">
    </Step>
</test>
```

I try to do this with:

1. register the pigbank.jar
2. then load with xmlloader

   `data = LOAD '/tmp/xmldatademo.xml'

   USING XMLLoader('Step') AS (Step:chararray);`

How can  I get the detail property?

Comment: Step TestResultInfo=" " TestElapsedTimeSec="0" TestResult="Pass" StepNumber="1" GUIResponseTime="0" TestDateTimeStarted="11/20/2012 11:01:14 PM" StepDescription="Ampere CMQMR -- Map CMQMR Driver" StepName="ProcMapCMQMRDriver_Foxconn"/

Comment: You have some errors in your xml file which makes it invalid XML. There is a `-` and a `+` between your tags which is probably not very useful for a XML parser and there is a closing tag missing in you `DataLog` element. Maybe your issues relate to that.